# Method where a type must have a subset of keys from another type

Tags: typescript

**Scenario**

I'm a typescript beginner trying to port the `mapProps` function below to typescript

```
const appState = {
    username: 'kimsagro',
    numberOfLogins: 2,
}

mapProps(appState, {
    username: x => x.toUpperCase()
})
// result: ​​​​​{ username: 'KIMSAGRO', numberOfLogins: 2 }​​​​​

mapProps(appState, {
    username: x => x.toUpperCase(),
    numberOfLogins: x => x + 1,
}) 
// ​​​​​result: { username: 'KIMSAGRO', numberOfLogins: 3 }​​​​​

// naive implementation that doesn't handle nested objects but provides a 
// starting point
const mapProps = (obj, fns) =>
    Object.keys(fns).reduce(
        (acc, curr) => ({
            ...acc,
            ...{ [curr]: fns[curr](obj[curr]) },
        }),
        obj,
    )
```

**Issue 1 - Type signature**

I wanted to make sure that

- The `fns` object `must` only contain keys found in the `obj` object
- The `fns` object `can` provide only a subset of keys found in the `obj` object
- Each value in the `fns` object is a function from that value's type to the same type

After some trial and error I arrived at the following type signature, however I'm not sure if its correct

```
const mapProps = <T, K extends { [P in keyof T]?: (x: T[P]) => T[P] }>(obj: T, fns: K): T => {
    // implementation here
    return obj
}
```

Given the following code, I was expecting the compiler to know that `x` has type `number`, but instead it has type `any` causing a `Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.` warning

```
interface IAppState {
    username: string,
    numberOfLogins: number
}

const appState: IAppState = {
    username: 'kimsagro',
    numberOfLogins: 2,
}

mapProps(appState, {
    // Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type
    numberOfLogins: x => x + 1
})
```

**UPDATE**

I've just noticed that this type signature doesn't detect invalid keys in all scenarios

```
// valid
mapProps(appState, {
    numberOfLogins: (x: number) => x + 1
})

// invalid
mapProps(appState, {
  notAPropertyOfAppState:(x: number) => x + 1
})

// valid ???
mapProps(appState, {
    numberOfLogins: (x: number) => x + 1,
    notAPropertyOfAppState:(x: number) => x + 1
})
```

I have create a [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IAppState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20username%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numberOfLogins%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20appState%3A%20IAppState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20username%3A%20'kimsagro'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numberOfLogins%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mapProps%20%3D%20%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20(x%3A%20T%5BP%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BP%5D%20%7D%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20fns%3A%20K)%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(Object.keys(fns)%20as%20(keyof%20T)%5B%5D).reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(acc%2C%20curr)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...acc%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%7B%20%5Bcurr%5D%3A%20fns%5Bcurr%5D!(obj%5Bcurr%5D)%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%0D%0AmapProps(appState%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numberOfLogins%3A%20(x%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%201%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0AmapProps(appState%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20notAPropertyOfAppState%3A(x%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%201%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0AmapProps(appState%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numberOfLogins%3A%20(x%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20notAPropertyOfAppState%3A(x%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%201%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A) to reproduce

**Issue 2 - implementation**

I tried to implement the method as below but it doesn't compile

```
const mapProps = <T, K extends { [P in keyof T]?: (x: T[P]) => T[P] }>(obj: T, fns: K): T =>
    (Object.keys(fns) as (keyof K)[]).reduce(
        (acc, curr) => ({
            ...acc,
            // Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
            // Type '((x: T[keyof K]) => T[keyof K]) | undefined'
            // has no compatible call signatures.
            ...{ [curr]: fns[curr](obj[curr]) },
        }),
        obj,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second issue is easy to fix, since keys of `K` are the same as `T` but optional, `fns[curr]` will be `((x: T[keyof K]) => T[keyof K]) | undefined`. In this case we care certain that `fns[curr]` can't be null even though the compiler can't prove it, so we can use a not null assertion (`!`):

```
(Object.keys(fns) as (keyof T)[]).reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ({
        ...acc,
        ...{ [curr]: fns[curr]!(obj[curr]) }, // the ! does the magic
    }),
    obj,
)
```

The first issue is a bit more tricky. The compiler will check the parameters, but when inferring the types of the parameters to `mapProps`, the information to type the callbacks will not be available and thus will be available and thus typescript will infer them as `any`  and then not reconsider the decision.

One option is to specify the type parameter explicitly:

```
const mapProps = <T>(obj: T, fns: { [P in keyof T]?: (x: T[P]) => T[P] }): T => /* ... */
mapProps<IAppState>(appState, {
    numberOfLogins: x => x + 1
})
```

A workaround for this issue that keeps inference, would be to use a function that returns a function, with the first call fixing T and thus the information to type the callback parameters is available:

```
function mapProps <T>(obj: T) {
    return (fns: { [P in keyof T]?: (x: T[P]) => T[P] }): T =>
    (Object.keys(fns) as (keyof T)[]).reduce(
        (acc, curr) => ({
            ...acc,
            ...{ [curr]: fns[curr]!(obj[curr]) },
        }),
        obj,
    )
}

mapProps(appState)({
    numberOfLogins: x => x 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response .. the function returning a function works perfectly however I did notice a scenario in which the original signature allowed invalid keys.. I have updated the question and would love your input

Comment: @kimsagro I don't use the `K` parameter intentionally in my code, I meant to mention it but I forgot. `K extends... ` means `K` can have the properties of `T` but it can also have more. `K` just needs to be a subtype of the constraint. If you don't use generics excess property checks kick in and you get an error

Comment: ahhhhh, that explains it